# Get hardware manufacturer and system model number in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, system-information

I'm trying to get the hardware manufacturer (e.g. "Dell") and the model number (e.g. "Latitude E6320") using vb.net but I'm having no luck.

I've tried

```
Dim opSearch As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
Dim opInfo As ManagementObject
For Each opInfo In opSearch.Get()
    Return opInfo("manufacturer").ToString()
Next
```

Though this returns "Microsoft Corporation" not "Dell".

Comment: Never underestimate the ability of a PC vendor to cut corners.  An important survival strategy when it comes down to pennies to compete with Asia.  Never overestimate a more worth-while project to work on for a programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are polling the wrong WMI class/hive.  Of course Microsoft is the OS manufacturer; what you need is `Win32_ComputerSystem`:

```
Imports System.Management


cs = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objMgmt In cs.Get
   _Manufacturer = objMgmt("manufacturer").ToString()
   _Model = objMgmt("model").ToString()
   _SystemType = objMgmt("systemtype").ToString
   _totalMem = objMgmt("totalphysicalmemory").ToString()
Next
```

Manufacturer will be something like "Dell, Inc", Model comes out spot on with mine, but has been known to sometimes include internal sub model identifiers.  System type comes back as "x64-based PC" on mine.

MS has a WMI query builder somewhere to help fnd and use the right query, though it generates very wordy code.

Comment: @rabbit, I should also mention that CodeProject has a SysInfo type app which displays **all** the WMI system values.  It is a bit dated in that it stops at XP or Vista, but it is helpful in that it has **all** the keys, properties and classes (at least as of that time).

Comment: leaving the link for the WMI query builder, as I recently found this answer helpful and searched it up: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try in a console application.  Just remember to add the System.Management reference to your project.  You need to access the Win32_ComputerSystem not the Win32_OperatingSystem.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim objCS As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim manufacturerName As String

    'objOS = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
    objCS = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objMgmt In objCS.Get
        manufacturerName = objMgmt("manufacturer").ToString()
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " & manufacturerName)
End Sub
```

Hope it helps.