# VB.net software and hardware informations

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how can I get the software and hardware informations of my machine with VB.Net ?? (Eg: memory card , hard drive, graphics card , microprocessor)
Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get hardware Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908902/get-hardware-info)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get hardware information such as Graphic Card capabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079786/get-hardware-information-such-as-graphic-card-capabilities) And there is also  [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22799153/1070452)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetDrives method. Here's the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx